# Unit testing for Splay Tree in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, tree

I am creating a test class for the following code. splay_test.py which is the unit test code for [splay tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree). I needed help with writing unit tests for python to get %100 coverage. I am very bad at unit testing but have started off ok. just need someone to help me finish it off and maybe find any more bugs. My coverage for some reason isn't connecting the two files together so I can't see what my overall coverage is.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = self.right = None

    def equals(self, node):
        return self.key == node.key


class SplayTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.header = Node(None)  # For splay()

    def insert(self, key):
        if (self.root == None):
            self.root = Node(key)
            return #test

        self.splay(key)
        if self.root.key == key:
            # If the key is already there in the tree, don't do anything.
            return

        n = Node(key)
        if key < self.root.key:
            n.left = self.root.left
            n.right = self.root
            self.root.left = None
        else:
            n.right = self.root.right
            n.left = self.root
            self.root.right = None
        self.root = n

    def remove(self, key):
        self.splay(key)
        if key != self.root.key:
            raise 'key not found in tree' # do

        # Now delete the root.
        if self.root.left == None:
            self.root = self.root.right
        else:
            x = self.root.right
            self.root = self.root.left
            self.splay(key)
            self.root.right = x

    def findMin(self):
        if self.root == None:
            return None
        x = self.root
        while x.left != None:
            x = x.left
        self.splay(x.key)
        return x.key

    def findMax(self):
        if self.root == None:
            return None
        x = self.root
        while (x.right != None):
            x = x.right
        self.splay(x.key)
        return x.key

    def find(self, key): # test
        if self.root == None:
            return None
        self.splay(key)
        if self.root.key != key:
            return None
        return self.root.key

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.root == None

    def splay(self, key): # test
        l = r = self.header
        t = self.root
        self.header.left = self.header.right = None
        while True:
            if key < t.key:
                if t.left == None:
                    break
                if key < t.left.key:
                    y = t.left
                    t.left = y.right
                    y.right = t
                    t = y
                    if t.left == None:
                        break
                r.left = t
                r = t
                t = t.left
            elif key > t.key:
                if t.right == None:
                    break
                if key > t.right.key:
                    y = t.right
                    t.right = y.left
                    y.left = t
                    t = y
                    if t.right == None:
                        break
                l.right = t
                l = t
                t = t.right
            else:
                break
        l.right = t.left
        r.left = t.right
        t.left = self.header.right
        t.right = self.header.left
        self.root = t
```

What I have so far

```
import unittest
from splay import SplayTree


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.keys = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        self.t = SplayTree()
        for key in self.keys:
            self.t.insert(key)

    def testInsert(self):
        for key in self.keys:
            self.assertEquals(key, self.t.find(key))

    def testRemove(self):
        for key in self.keys:
            self.t.remove(key)
            self.assertEquals(self.t.find(key), None)

    def testLargeInserts(self):
        t = SplayTree()
        nums = 40000
        gap = 307
        i = gap
        while i != 0:
            t.insert(i)
            i = (i + gap) % nums

    def testIsEmpty(self):
        self.assertFalse(self.t.isEmpty())
        t = SplayTree()
        self.assertTrue(t.isEmpty())

    def testMinMax(self):
        self.assertEquals(self.t.findMin(), 0)
        self.assertEquals(self.t.findMax(), 9)
```

Tests I have done so far

```
import unittest
from splay import SplayTree


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.keys = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        self.t = SplayTree()
        for key in self.keys:
            self.t.insert(key)

    def testInsert(self):
        for key in self.keys:
            self.assertEquals(key, self.t.find(key))

    def testRemove(self):
        for key in self.keys:
            self.t.remove(key)
            self.assertEquals(self.t.find(key), None)

    def testLargeInserts(self):
        t = SplayTree()
        nums = 40000
        gap = 307
        i = gap
        while i != 0:
            t.insert(i)
            i = (i + gap) % nums

    def testIsEmpty(self):
        self.assertFalse(self.t.isEmpty())
        t = SplayTree()
        self.assertTrue(t.isEmpty())

    def testMinMax(self):
        self.assertEquals(self.t.findMin(), 0)
        self.assertEquals(self.t.findMax(), 9)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Rather than writing an `equals` method, consider using `__eq__`; do some reading here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__

Comment: @Reinderien You have a point about that, but as far as i can see, he hasn't make any `equals` method, he's rather using an [assertion](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/assert-statement).

Comment: @SebasSBM Look harder :) There's an `equals` under the `Node` class.

Comment: @Reinderien in that case, `__eq__` usage would fit better, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

You've already done a pretty good job adding these tests and covering a big chunk of the code under test.

The problem is, if we look at the [*branch coverage*](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.3.4/branch.html), we'll see that quite a few of the branches are not reached as the implementation is relatively ["complex"](https://github.com/PyCQA/mccabe) - by [code complexity standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity):

```
python -m pytest test_tree.py --cov-branch --cov=tree --cov-report html
```

Using `pytest` and `pytest-cov` plugin, `tree` here is the module/package name for which to measure coverage.

Other observations:

- `self.assertEquals()` is deprecated in favor of `self.assertEqual()`
- even though `setUp` and `tearDown` are the legacy camel-case Junit-inspired names, consider following PEP8 and naming your methods in an [lower_case_with_underscores style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36)
- look into defining your tree as a [`pytest` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html)
- look into *property-based-testing* with [Hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as a means to generate possible input nodes for your tree
- focus on the more complex parts first as this is where the possibility of having a problem is higher - the `splay()` method should probably be tested separately and directly checking all the major variations of re-balancing the tree when a new node is added